# Parse Json using SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am able to get the entire JSon array parsed. It outputs to console with no issue. I can't seem to get the individual params from the array... my json looks like:

```
[{
        City = NYC;
        Device = "<null>";
        DisplayAs = "Steve Hutson";
        FirstName = Steve;
        LastName = Hutson;
        MobilePhone = "000-000-0000";
        Org = "<null>";
        Region = "";
        Role = INSPECTOR;
        SupervisorID = "73990";
        email = "email@email.com";
        fLast = shutson;
        "gz_modtimestamp" = "2015-07-28 14:42:41";
        id = 96;
        isActive = YES;
        lastupdated = "<null>";
        sendemail = 1;
        token = "<null>";
        userpassword = "xxx";
    },{
        City = DET;
        Device = "<null>";
        DisplayAs = "Filipe Washington";
        FirstName = Filipe;
        LastName = Washington;
        MobilePhone = "000-000-0000";
        Org = "<null>";
        Region = "";
        Role = INSPECTOR;
        SupervisorID = "6567";
        email = "email@email.com";
        fLast = shutson;
        "gz_modtimestamp" = "2015-07-28 13:02:09";
        id = 93;
        isActive = YES;
        lastupdated = "<null>";
        sendemail = 1;
        token = "<null>";
        userpassword = "xxx";
    }]
```

In my main ViewController.swift file my json request looks like:

```
    var myData:NSData = getJSON("http://xxxx/getusersData.php")

    var myDict:NSArray = parseJSON(myData)

    println(myDict)
```

This prints my entire json object which is perfect. However my issue is, how do I get only the FirstName's in an array? By index this works:

`println(myDict[0]["FirstName"])` how ever, it only brings back one item.

I am trying to insert specific json items into sqlite which i am using SQLite.swift but i need to know how to retrieve specific item parameters as I would if i was using AJAX.

I am trying to retrieve FirstName, Email and UserPassword info.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the JSON object and retrieve that info:

```
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
    var firstName = subJson["FirstName"].stringValue
    var email = subJson["email"].stringValue
    var userPassword = subJson["userpassword"].stringValue
    // Build the sqlite query with the variables here 
}
```

As a clarification, you don't access the values directly as in `json["FirstName"]`, you must also use the type functions from SwiftyJSON. In your case they're both strings, so `stringValue` is used. If you needed and `int`, it'd be `intValue`.

There's also the option of just `json["FirstName"].string` in case the field is optional. Take a look at the [readme](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)